# PHP if SESSION exists but is null

Tags: php, session

How I can check in PHP if SESSION exists but is null.

I have really old self made platform, where visitor can log in as "guest", it sets `$_SESSION "guest"` but it is `NULL`.

Now I wan't to show some specific content to only registered. If I check
`isset($_SESSION['guest']), is_null($_SESSION['guest'])` or `is_null($_SESSION['guest'] === FALSE` they all return same.

How I can check if guest session exists but is `null`?

Comment: All of those are meant to return the same, they operate on boolean values 1,0 true, false. You would be better to be checking if there is an active session instead, just as you would to check the user is logged in as a registered user instead, you could add a new element to the session "registered" with a true or false value assigned to it then check that.

Comment: Obvious first question! Thats script does have a `session_start()` at the top doesn't it

Comment: RTM http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-null.php

Comment: yes, sessions are set of course. the sessions guest exists BUT AS NULL. so I found a way to find if sessions[key] exists. foreach($_SESSION as $key => $val) { if( $key == 'guest') $guest = true; } that way I know if there is key "guest" even if its null... after thinking about this, I feel so dumb, it wasn't never about the value but key... I wanna whack my head to wall...

Comment: did you just answer your own question? ^

Comment: I think so, go ahead and take credit for it, I accept it if you do so because it works.

Comment: Actually @Diamonte that credit should go to you. Stack lets you post your own answer, which IMHO, you should.

Answer (score 1):

This question was not yet really answered (albeit they found a way to foreach over the array to look-up the `'guest'` key in the `$_SESSION` array).

---

The problem is to check an array entry that is null. Reason is that a check with `isset($_SESSION['guest'])` returns false as the member is `null`. Cf. https://php.net/isset .

A function that works is *array_key_exists()*, as it takes all members into account, including those which are `null`. It really tests if the key exists in the array.

Example for the case that the *guest* member is null:

```
$_SESSION['guest']; # null, no warning
isset($_SESSION['guest']); # false
array_key_exists('guest', $_SESSION); # true
```

Naturally, using foreach works as well, but it requires more code and the functionality already exists with the *array_key_exists()* function.

Reference: https://php.net/array_key_exists – see especially *[Example #2 array_key_exists() vs isset()](https://php.net/array_key_exists#example-5016)*.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['guest']) && is_null($_SESSION['guest']))
{
    // your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if($_SESSION['guest'] == "")
{
    // code
}
```

Comment: May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `empty` instead, for example:

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['guest']) && !empty($_SESSION['guest'])) {
    //Session is not null or empty
}
else
{
    //Session is null or empty
}
```